# Changing an extention method from linq-to-sql to entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I'm changing my project from working with Linq-to-SQL to working with Entity Framework.

I have some extention methods that extend the classes created by LINQ and I'm wondering how to change them to work with the entities instead

Here's an example.

```
public static int GetPublishedArticlesCount(this Table<Article> source)
    {
        return GetPublishedArticles(source.Context as DataContext, null).Count();
    }
```

This method gets the number of published articles. Instead of using **`this Table<Article>`**, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the [ObjectQuery<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx) class.

```
public static int GetPublishedArticlesCount(this ObjectQuery<Article> source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Analog of Table<> (linq 2 sql) in EntityFramework is ObjectQuery

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster metioned you could use ObjectQuery to get the result.

To make the method more generic as an extension method to ObjectQuery & get count of any type perhaps this might help:

```
public static int GetCount<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> query){
    return query.CreateQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name).Count();
}
```

NOTE: I am writing this code from top of my head, might has some sytax errors...

HTH.